# VMWare vCenter Converter does not continue

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vcenter

I've been trying to clone a vm with the vCenter Converter 5.1 software, but I am having trouble with the 2nd vm I tried to do. The first completed with no errors. The second however, will not let me continue on the Destination Location screen on the wizard for converting.

I select the correct datastore, but it does not allow me to continue (the "Next" button is grayed out). However, it does not tell me why, nor does it show anything special in the logs. Anyone out there with experience with this?

The weird thing is, I was able to clone the VM to a different server, but I am still not able to clone it to the server I want it to clone to.

Comment: Does the destination datastore have enough available space for the VM?

Comment: Way enough - the VM is about 30GB, and there's 200GB free on the server.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the screen you're getting stopped at?

Comment: At this time I don't have access to the server, so this is a general sceenshot I found: http://docs.trendmicro.com/all/ent/dda/v2.95/en-us/dda_2.95_olh/images/converter_location.png , my screen is pretty much the same, except that I don't have a virtual machine version option. Which is weird, cause I could select that when I cloned it to the different server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloning works in the older version, 4.0. No idea why, but it does work perfectly.

Edit: this seems to be because of a compatibility issue with ESXi 3.5, vCenter Converter 5 does not support it.

Comment: Were you P2Ving directly to an ESXi box. If so, which version of ESXi?

Comment: No - virtual to virtual, from VMWare Server 1.02 to ESXi 3.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a problem with your initial server, try to make a check disk to see if you don't have any error

Comment: This answer seems a little weak. Perhaps you could elaborate it a bit?

Comment: I don't think that would be the problem, since I was able to clone the VM to a different server. I would expect there to be some issue with the datastore on the destination server, maybe a compatibility issue, but I do not know, since the vCenter Converter doesn't tell me anything.